# C: Issue with setting soft limit using RLIMIT_FSIZE

Tags: c

I was reading the Manual Pages about getrlimt/setrlimit and I was following the examples accordingly.

I am trying to set the "soft" limit, but when I set the soft limit and print it out, it comes out completely wrong.

Examples: I set the soft limit to 50, I get The soft limit is 219030298624.
I set the soft limit to 100, I get The soft limit is 42953954893824. 
I set the soft limit to 100000 as listed in the code below and I get the same thing as above.

What is going on?

```
        struct rlimit limit;
        getrlimit (RLIMIT_FSIZE, &limit);
        limit.rlim_cur = 100000;
        setrlimit (RLIMIT_FSIZE, &limit);


        struct rlimit rl;
        getrlimit (RLIMIT_CPU, &rl);
        rl.rlim_cur = 1;     
        setrlimit (RLIMIT_CPU, &rl);

        printf("The soft limit is %llu\n", limit.rlim_cur);
```

Comment: I think you have a bug as well. When setting the RLIMIT_CPU, you use `rl`, but in your printf you are printing the value of `limit` which you used when settings RLIMIT_FSIZE.

Comment: @user590028 Yes, that is because I wanted to print the soft limit of the File size to make sure it was what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setrlimit` does not return the current value. You need to call `getrlimit` after setting the value to retrieve the current value.

```
 struct rlimit rl;
 getrlimit (RLIMIT_CPU, &rl);
 rl.rlim_cur = 1;     
 setrlimit (RLIMIT_CPU, &rl);

 getrlimit (RLIMIT_CPU, &rl);
 printf("The soft limit is %llu\n", rl.rlim_cur);
```

Or you can use `prlimit` to both set and get in one call http://linux.die.net/man/2/prlimit

Comment: You are correct and I thank you so much. I have spent he last two hours banging my head against a wall.

Comment: NOTES
       The prlimit system call is supported since Linux 2.6.36, older kernels will break this program

Answer (score 0):

`%llu` is not necessarily a valid format specifier for `rlim_t`. This is the source of the nonsensical huge values; you're invoking UB by passing mismatching types to `printf`. Cast to `long long` and the value printed should be correct.