# What is the right way to print a value of type rlim_t?

Tags: c

I am using the `getrlimit()` function to get the maximum stack size on my system. This function stores both the current limit and the maximum limit in a `struct` with two `rlim_t` fields. I want to print these values.

I found [this link](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/resource.h.html) that suggests that `rlim_t` is an `unsigned` integer type, so I used the `PRIuMAX` macro for the conversion specifier, casting the value to `(uintmax_t)`. I noticed that I could omit the cast without generating any warnings; is the cast really necessary here?

After digging through several header files, I found that `rlim_t` is a `typedef` for `unsigned long` on my system. So I could also use the `%lu` conversion specifier, and do away with the cast.

I don't think that I can assume that `rlim_t` is always an `unsigned long`, so it seems better to use the first method to improve portability. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28529326/6879826) that suggests that `%llu` may not always be a valid conversion specifier for `rlim_t`, and advocates casting to `long long`. What is the best way to print a value of type `rlim_t`?

Here is a short, illustrative program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct rlimit stacklim;
    rlim_t cur_bytes, max_bytes;

    if (getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, &stacklim) == 0) {
        cur_bytes = stacklim.rlim_cur;
        max_bytes = stacklim.rlim_max;
    } else {
        perror("Error in getrlimit()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    puts("Maximum Stack Size");
    printf("Soft limit: %" PRIuMAX " bytes\n", (uintmax_t)cur_bytes);
    printf("Hard limit: %" PRIuMAX " bytes\n", (uintmax_t)max_bytes);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your existing solution is fine and you should use the cast in case the type changes in a different version of system headers.

Comment: Agree with @M.M — if you're using `PRIuMAX` and aren't sure that `cur_bytes` is already a type compatible with `uintmax_t` under the default promotion rules that apply to formatted arguments to `printf()`, then the cast is necessary to ensure safety across platforms.  Even if you get away with it on your current machine, it may not work on other platforms — don't risk it when the cost is negligible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments to the original question, the cast is necessary to ensure that the type matches the conversion specification. The system headers may not define the type of `rlim_t` to be `uintmax_t`, but since `rlim_t` is an `unsigned` integer type, the cast to `uintmax_t` is safe.

The above solution using the `PRIuMAX` macro is fine, but since C99 there has also been the `j` type modifier, used for printing values of type `intmax_t` and `uintmax_t`:

```
printf("Soft limit: %ju bytes\n", (uintmax_t)cur_bytes);
printf("Hard limit: %ju bytes\n", (uintmax_t)max_bytes);
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted solution is great. It is a safe route.

I thought that it is worth adding that in the relevant Linux [manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrlimit.2.html), the sole example provided (very bottom of the webpage) uses

> intmax_t

for displaying each member of a `rlimit` structure when the first argument of `getrlimit` is the macro `RLIMIT_CPU` (limit, in seconds, on the amount of CPU time that the process can consume).

This can be "unlimited". An "unlimited" value occurs when the member has value equal to the value of the `RLIM_INFINITY` macro, which on my system is defined as `0xffffffffffffffffuLL` or 2<sup>64</sup> - 1.

This would suggest that it is safe to cast to `intmax_t` which has associated specifier `%jd`.

Although you did not ask for this, the following program may be of help to others that read this post. The following program prints the values of the members of each `rlimit` structure for every possible value of the `resource` argument (the first argument) of `getrlimit`. This program casts to `intmax_t` (with specifier `%jd`) as an example, though casting to `uintmax_t` (with specifier `%ju`) is also perfectly acceptable.

```
#include <sys/resource.h> // for rlimit struct, getrlimit(), and macros
#include <stdio.h> // for printf
#include <stdint.h> // for uintmax_t
#include <string.h> // for strlen()

/* "Get Variable Name": direct preprocessor to stringize variable v. */
#define GVN(v) (#v)

int main(void) {
    /* Array containing int macros */
    int limits[] = {
        RLIMIT_AS, RLIMIT_CORE, RLIMIT_CPU, RLIMIT_DATA, RLIMIT_FSIZE,
        RLIMIT_LOCKS, RLIMIT_MEMLOCK, RLIMIT_MSGQUEUE, RLIMIT_NICE,
        RLIMIT_NOFILE, RLIMIT_NPROC, RLIMIT_RSS, RLIMIT_RTPRIO,
        RLIMIT_RTTIME, RLIMIT_SIGPENDING, RLIMIT_STACK
    };
    /* Array containing the names of above macros */
    char* limits_names[] = {GVN(RLIMIT_AS), GVN(RLIMIT_CORE), GVN(RLIMIT_CPU),
        GVN(RLIMIT_DATA), GVN(RLIMIT_FSIZE), GVN(RLIMIT_LOCKS),
        GVN(RLIMIT_MEMLOCK), GVN(RLIMIT_MSGQUEUE), GVN(RLIMIT_NICE),
        GVN(RLIMIT_NOFILE), GVN(RLIMIT_NPROC), GVN(RLIMIT_RSS),
        GVN(RLIMIT_RTPRIO), GVN(RLIMIT_RTTIME), GVN(RLIMIT_SIGPENDING),
        GVN(RLIMIT_STACK)
    };

    /* getrlimit modifies this structure */
    struct rlimit limit;
    /* get length of the arrays */
    size_t len_limits = sizeof(limits) / sizeof(limits[0]);
    /* stores number of characters of longest macro name */
    size_t max_len_names = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0, temp; i < len_limits; i++) 

        if ((temp = strlen(limits_names[i])) > max_len_names)
            max_len_names = temp;


    printf("\n");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len_limits; i++) {

        /* getrlimit returns 0 on success, -1 otherwise */
        if (getrlimit(limits[i], &limit) != 0) {
            printf("\n%s (error in getrlimit() with this arg)\n\n",
                limits_names[i]);
            continue;
        }

        /* RLIM_INFINITY is 0xffffffffffffffffuLL on my setup */
        /* RLIM_INFINITY denotes no limit on a resource */
        if (limit.rlim_cur == RLIM_INFINITY)
            printf("%-*s (soft): unlimited\n", (int) max_len_names,
                limits_names[i]);
        else
            printf("%-*s (soft): %ju\n", (int) max_len_names, limits_names[i],
                (uintmax_t) limit.rlim_cur);

        if (limit.rlim_max == RLIM_INFINITY)
            printf("%-*s (hard): unlimited\n", (int) max_len_names,
                limits_names[i]);
        else
            printf("%-*s (hard): %ju\n", (int) max_len_names, limits_names[i],
                (uintmax_t) limit.rlim_max);

    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I believe it is an unsigned long.

```
printf("Soft limit: %lu" PRIuMAX " bytes\n", cur_bytes);
printf("Hard limit: %lu" PRIuMAX " bytes\n", max_bytes);
```

Comment: Well, you need to remove the `PRIuMAX` macros from that code, and as I stated in my question: "I found that `rlim_t` is a `typedef` for `unsigned long` on my system." The question is, can I assume that it is _always_ `unsigned long`, or is it better to use the widest possible `unsigned` integer type available?